# WP7: Getting started with UnitTest Framework: XamlParseException

Tags: unit-testing, windows-phone-7

I want to add Unit Tests to my WP7 project. I followed the tutrials on http://smartypantscoding.com/a-cheat-sheet-for-unit-testing-silverlight-apps-on-windows-phone-7 to get started with unit tests. But I cannot manage to get it running.

I followed all the steps from the tutorial and created the basictests.

But as soon as I want to start the project, Visual Studio throws an error:

**XamlParseException occured**
Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key typeNameConverter [Line: 47 Position: 24]

Line 47 refers to the initial CreateTestPage:

```
private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
            SystemTray.IsVisible = false; 
Line47:     var testPage = UnitTestSystem.CreateTestPage() as IMobileTestPage; 
            BackKeyPress += (x, xe) => xe.Cancel = testPage.NavigateBack(); 
            (Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Content = testPage; 
}
```

Hope you can help me out!
thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably using Jeff Willcox's toolkit for Windows Phone 7. If you want to run it under  new Windows Phone try to use new version of toolkit as I did.
Try to use Jeff Willcox's toolkit for Windows Phone 7.5 (Mango) Get it here: http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2011/06/updated-ut-mango-bits/
Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered this yesterday and found that `App.xaml` was misconfigured. Using guesswork (i.e. what interfaces implement `IValueConverter`?), I found this solution, which seems to work very well.

First, add this namespace to your `<Application>` namespace:

```
xmlns:Client="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Silverlight.Testing.Client;assembly=Microsoft.Silverlight.Testing">
```

Then add this to `<Application>`:

```
<Application.Resources>
  <Client:TypeNameVisibilityConverter x:Name="typeNameConverter" />
  <Client:FontWeightConverter x:Name="fontWeightConverter" />
</Application.Resources>
```

I hope this is useful to someone.

I can confirm that Michael Dumont's solution does work as well, but you can't view test run details which is annoying when attempting to view information for broken tests when you don't have the debugger attached for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your Unit test project is for .Net Framework 3.0 or 3.5 and use the [Unit Test Framework Assemblies compatible with Mango](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2011/06/updated-ut-mango-bits/) created by Jeff Wilcox.  I had the same error when the project is for .Net Framework 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

I received this error as well and stubbed the ValueConverters it was looking for and was able to successfully get the framework working.

App.xaml

```
<!--Application Resources-->
<Application.Resources>
    <s:typeNameConverter x:Name="typeNameConverter"></s:typeNameConverter>
    <s:fontWeightConverter x:Name="fontWeightConverter"></s:fontWeightConverter>
</Application.Resources>
```

Value Converters

```
public class typeNameConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class fontWeightConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And the exception refers to the XAML in the TestPage. So you're posting the wrong code.

Anyway, the error is very clear. The declared `typeNameConverter` in your XAML, is missing. Most likely you forgot to add a reference to the assembly declaring it, or to update the xmlns so it points on a different assembly, and not just a different namespace.